# Store queue of strings in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing an application using jQuery (with the jPlayer plugin) that needs to store a queue of songs to play.  I plan to just simply store the strings of the song names in the queue... is there a really good, simple queue implementation in javascript that anyone would recommend?  jQuery's queue doesn't seem to be what I want since it deals with functions, which is way more complicated than I need.

Thanks

Comment: If you rule out functions, you rule out JavaScript. :'(

Comment: I'm not ruling out functions... i just want to store strings, so using a queue that is built to store functions seems like overkill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply use an array to store your song :

```
var mySongs = [];
mySongs.push('myNewSong');
```

Comment: +1. To act as a queue you need to pop the first element of the array with `shift()` instead of with `pop()`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, orip